# Using CodeIgniter framework. How to get_where but limit the results to the past 12 hours?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, timestamp, between

Basically I have a whole database table dedicated to user-submissions. Each row has a column of `timestamp` which is the php `time()` of when the user submitted, and of `username` which I use to filter the table to just a particular username.

But the username has multiple rows (let's say more than 9000 rows).

How can I filter that even further to just the past 12 hours? Which is `43200 seconds`

And how can I do it efficiently?

I can't seem to find a CodeIgniter `db query` function that can limit the results via something like `BETWEEN` `now` and `now - 43200`

I MUST NOTE THAT THE `timestamp` FIELD IS OF TYPE `BIGINT(20)` AND IT STORES A PHP TIMESTAMP `time()`

Comment: Can you show us your query? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @FMashiro - currently it is `$query = $this->db->get_where('reports', array('username' => $username));` but not sure the best way to EFFICIENTLY limit the results to just the past `43200 seconds`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use where clause `where("timestamp_column <=",$time);`

```
 $time =time()-43200;
 $this->db->select("colum1,column2");
 $this->db->where("timestamp_column >=",$time);
 $this->db->from("tabl_name");
 $result = $this->db->get()->result();
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `>=`?

Answer (score 1):

use below query

```
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE username = "username" and `Date` > NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR
```

in codeigniter

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM reports WHERE username = "username" and `Date` > NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR")->result_array();
```